# calling a function from static function

Tags: c++

how can i call a function which computes with input parameters from an another static function.

say,

```
class X
{
   static void xyz();

   static int pqr(int, int);
};

void X::xyz()
{
...pqr(10,20);

}

int X::pqr(int t1, int t2)
{

  return t1*t2;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more detailed in your question here - what is it *exactly* that you want to do ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `void X::xyz()` instead of `X::void xyz()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call instance methods off an instance of the class. Otherwise, just call it off the class.

```
X::pqr(10, 20)
```

Comment: The qualification is not even needed if you are calling from within the class context (which includes the definition of other static class member functions)

Answer (score 1):

1) Call it just like pqr(10, 20);

2) You have an error in xyz() definition. It should be

```
void X::xyz()
```

Note: you don't need static keywords in the definition of the function, only in the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague, but it looks like you just need to do something like this:

```
void X::xyz()
{
    int foo = X::pqr(10, 20);
}

int X::pqr(int t1, int t2)
{
    return t1*t2;
}
```

Comment: The class qualification is not needed as `X::xyz` is already within the class context.

Comment: @David: True - the class qualification is redundant but harmless - I guess it depends on your preferred coding style.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line:

```
static X::void xyz()
```

to this:

```
void X::xyz()
```